# (Vue.js) Same component with different routes

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js

I would like to use the same component for different routes in a Vue.js application.

I currently have something like this:

---

**main.js**

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/route-1', name: 'route-1', component: MyComponent },
    { path: '/route-2', name: 'route-2', component: MyComponent },
    { path: '/route-3', name: 'route-3', component: MyComponent },

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})
```

---

**myComponent.vue**

```
<ul>
    <li><router-link to="/route-1">Route 1</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/route-2">Route 2</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/route-3">Route 3</router-link></li>
</ul>
```

---

When I type the route manually in the browser, everything is working well, but when I try to navigate between the routes using some of these *router-generated-links*, nothing happens. The route changes but the content is still the same. Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you are using same component so that's why nothing change, in fact only thing that's change is the route.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as Vue is trying to be optimal and reuse existing components. The behaviour you want to achieve used to be solved with a setting called `canReuse`, but that has been deprecated. The current recommended solution is to set a unique `:key` property on your `<router-view>` like so:

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

Check out this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dnxbzy6c/1/).

Comment: Works like a charm! I understand the reasons why that's the expected behaviour, but since I have three similar pages with just some content differences, I have to use three different routes to load the right content for each page. That's my very first project and maybe I will find a more elegant solution to achieve the same result. But yeah, thank you! :)

Comment: Duuuuuuddddeeeee I was going CRAZY. Glad I found this answer

Comment: Solution seems to no longer work with vue 3.3.10 (or higher). Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `watch` property, so your component will not waste time to reloading:

**index.js**
You might have something like this

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/users/:id',
    component: Vue.component('user', require('./comp/user.vue').default)
  }
]
```

**user.vue**

```
created(){
  // will fire on component first init
  this.init_component();
},
watch: {
  // will fire on route changes
//'$route.params.id': function(val, oldVal){ // Same
  '$route.path': function(val, oldVal){
    console.log(this.$route.params.id);
    this.init_component();
  }
},
methods: {
  init_component: function(){
    // do anything you need
    this.load_user_data_with_ajax();
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to make a note. If anybody is working with SSR template, things are a bit different. @mzgajner's answer does indeed recreate the component but will not trigger the asyncData again.

For that to happen, modify entry-client.js like this.

OLD:

```
const activated = matched.filter((c, i) => {
    return diffed || (diffed = (prevMatched[i] !== c))
})
```

NEW:

```
const activated = matched.filter((c, i) => {

    /*
        In my case I only needed this for 1 component
    */

    diffed = ((prevMatched[i] !== c) || c.name == 'p-page-property-map')

    return diffed
})
```