# Mapping multiple URLs to the same component with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my Vue 2.7.5 app (using Vue Router 3.5.4). I'm trying to map multiple URLs to the same component. Currently, I have a single route mapped to the component:

```js
{
  path: '/customer/:customerId',
  component: CustomerOrders
}
```

My goal is to add an optional `orderId` parameter, such that if a URL like `/customer/42/order/59` is accessed, then the same component is loaded, but the order with ID 59 is highlighted (the details of how the param is going to highlight the order are not important).

I tried changing the path to `/customer/:customerId/orders/:orderId?`, but this would no longer match any URLs of the form `/customer/:customerId` and would therefore be a breaking change.

My current solution is to use a child route:

```js
{
 path: '/customer/:customerId',
 component: CustomerOrders,
 children: [
   {
     path: 'order/:orderId',
     component: CustomerOrders
   }
  ]
}
```

This work as the `CustomerOrders` component is loaded by paths matching either `/customer/:customerId` or `/customer/:customerId/order/:orderId`, but it seems like a slightly convoluted approach and I'm not sure it's an appropriate use of child routes.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to register the same component for both routes:

```js
{
  path: '/customer/:customerId',
  name: 'CustomerOrders',
  component: () => import( '../views/CustomerOrders.vue'),
},
{
  path: '/customer/:customerId/order/:orderId',
  name: 'CustomerOrders',
  component: () => import( '../views/CustomerOrders.vue'),
},
```

An exact solution that you are looking for is **parsing params manually**:

```js
{
  path: '/customer/:param+',
  name: 'CustomerOrders',
  component: () => import( '../views/CustomerOrders.vue'),
  props: router => {
    const params = router.params;
    const split = params.param.split('/');
    params.customerId = split[0];
    if (split.length > 2) {
      params.orderId = split[2];
    }
  },
},
```

Here the `:params+` ensures that a `customerId` and the rest of the route get caught. On the other hand, using `:params*` catches the `/customer` route without even a `customerId`.

**CAUTION** This approach also `/customers/42/...everything...`
The vue3 solution is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215026/how-to-set-dynamic-routes-with-multiple-dynamic-parameters-in-vue-3-vue-router).

**EDIT: the following approach cannot catch orderId**

Using an alias improves reusability and reduces rendering time but comes with a price of capturing params-change in a `watch` handler.

```js
{
  path: '/customer/:customerId',
  name: 'CustomerOrders',
  alias: '/customer/:customerId/order/:orderId',
  component: () => import( '../views/CustomerOrders.vue'),
},
```

In this case, your component doesn't get rebuilt by changing routes and also `onMount` or `beforeCreate` hooks don't get called either. To catch params-change add a proper `watch`:

```js
export default {
  name: 'CustomerOrders',
  watch: {
    '$route.params'() {
      console.log('params changed. Extract params manually and reload');
    },
  },
};
```

This issue is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603583/vue-js-same-component-with-different-routes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure it's legal to define 2 routes with the same name?

Comment: Sure. Vue Router supports `alias` that can be a path or an array of paths. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js

React Router event support and an array of paths for a specific component. It's a matter of reusability.

Comment: It's legal to have the same `name` multiple times, but when you navigate to `{ name: duplicatedName }` it will always resolve to the first match in the routes tree. I'd avoid it, on general principles.